# Vb6 Out of memory error

Tags: dll, vb6, out-of-memory

I've got a problem with vb6.
Using an HMI vb6 developed interface in a automated machine, it sometimes crashes with out of memory error.
initially it happens using a particular form, so i tried set it up well, now happens less time but in random form.
These forms are in a dll file and in HMI exe file.
I cannot debug that because it's quite difficult reproduce that error.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain HMI - cannot derive from context.

Comment: If this program contains even a single `DoEvents()` function call I'd start looking there.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Human Machine Interface (ie, PLC screen). As for the OP, has it always done this or just started? What is the app doing repeatedly that would use memory? Then it's just a matter of finding which resource you are not cleaning up properly over time.

Comment: Only sometimes this error happens, it's not repetitive. for example, now I have this problem after 4 days software is running.

Comment: @topshot: thanks for the expl.

Comment: Then it must be something that isn't done regularly in this program if it's totally random (unless perhaps this machine isn't in constant use). I assume this is a generic VB (or OS) error rather than one you are displaying so add in some more error handling so you can at least determine which routine it's in when it gets this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,
there was a couple of line that handles other modal forms despite the main current form was a modal too. so systems continue ping focus between different windows, after tot minutes, it crashes.